# Node JS save user options to config file?

Tags: json, node.js, yaml, config, fs

I've got a rather general question, I don't know what to search for..

I'm trying to let the user choose some options in my app.
Then I want to save those options on the server (*and load them, of course*).

What would be best practice to do this?

I want checkboxes in the browser.

- How do I get the server to know what has been clicked?
- How do I parse this (*ajax*) ?

Until now, the page only contains buttons, which call functions and send their command over sockets.
Do i have to do this for the checkboxes too?

Thanks

Comment: It's exactly the same as storing the user's profile information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather abstract question, but anyway ...

**For UI** you should choose smth. like [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/download/), [`ReactJS`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html), [`AngularJS`](https://angularjs.org/) if you wish, for user interaction.

For server-side data processing you need smth. that serves endpoints, some server. For this task there are also many variants, the possible one is [`Express`](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html). It will let you create some usable endpoints on which you will be able to send any data and process it.

And finally **saving of user options**. There are few variants:

1. Database storage (**very recommended**)
2. JSON/YAML file storage

It all depends on requirements, but I would recommend database storage anyway.

There are no strict practices on this particular case bec. it is particular abstract case and you should decide yourself knowing the task you need to accomplish.